# VBA Netting For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to net two for-next loop.

```
For j = 2 To rownum 'rownum=502
        For k = 3 To 7 Step 1 'ref_row step 1
        Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").range("D" & CStr(j + 1)) _
            = j 'Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("Transaction in Specified Period").range("P" & j).Value
        Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").range("E" & CStr(j + 1)) _
            = k 'Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").range("B" & k).Value
    Next k
Next j
```

What I get in the "CatSh" Sheet, is a looping number of J following the same number, which is the last number of k.

Anyone knows what is happening ?

Comment: To the spec, it's like 2-7, 3-7.4-7,etc. K never looped.

Comment: the step by step debugger is your friend

Comment: You are constantly overwriting in your k loop as j doesn't change.

Comment: but how so? I net these two loops completely. It should give me 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 3-3, 3-4, 3-5, etc. How can I possibly fix it?

Comment: @LiyuHe - where do you expect 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7 ... to appear? in what set of cells?

Comment: "Net"? Work it through, use the debugger as Philipp suggests and use the locals window to check the values of variables. I don't know what result you want so can't make a concrete suggestion.

Comment: Thx Phillip and SJR, I will try it when I arrive home. @Scott Holtzman Thanks man. I tried to answer you then I realized what I did wrong.  As SJR said, I am constantly overwriting my k loop. Because I wrote them all in j+1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account `j` *AND* `k` when deciding what row to write to.

This might be offset lower than you want, so you'll need to tweak it but if you want *every* item written in sequence with no gaps then the following should work:

```
For j = 2 To rownum 'rownum = 502
        For k = 3 To 7 Step 1 'ref_row step 1
        Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").Range("D" & CStr((j * (7 - 3 + 1)) + k)) _
            = j 'Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("Transaction in Specified Period").range("P" & j).Value
        Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").Range("E" & CStr((j * (7 - 3 + 1)) + k)) _
            = k 'Workbooks(tdrname).Worksheets("CatSh").range("B" & k).Value
    Next k
Next j
```

Note, the `7 - 3` within `CStr((j * (7 - 3 + 1)) + k))` will also need tweaking should you change the `For k = 3 To 7 Step 1` part of your loop definition.